# Media Query in Internet Explorer 11 reading last one

Tags: css, media-queries, internet-explorer-11

I tried out with some **@media** query as follows,

```
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) and (-ms-high-contrast:active), (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
    .breadcrumb.Connect {
        bottom: 176%;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 1920px) and (-ms-high-contrast:active), (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
    .breadcrumb.Connect {
        bottom: 181.5%;
        left: -30%;
        width: 160.2%;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1919px) and (-ms-high-contrast:active), (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
    .breadcrumb.Connect {
        bottom: 172.5%;
        left: -7.5%;
        width:115.2%;
    }
    div.newsletter-container-connect div.right-form-block {
        width: 43%;
    }
}
```

Whatever resolution I chosen example **1920px**, but the style for that element (**breadcrumb.Connect**) is overrides by the last rule (**(min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1919px)**).

Comment: How are you making sure that you are actually at 1920?

Comment: @Huangism I am using **IE11 Emulation in Developer tools** to resize the resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1919px)
```

This condition applies to widths larger than or equal to 1201px that are also less than or equal to 1919px, i.e. it’s never true. The comma has a lower precedence here than `and`, though, so `(-ms-high-contrast:none)` is causing every rule to be applied.

Comment: Tested and true http://jsfiddle.net/Lmq8ry9s/1/ compared to http://jsfiddle.net/Lmq8ry9s

Comment: Thanks @minitech. :) It's works. modified the code based on your comment got the espected result.

Answer (score 0):

There are two colliding media queries here and if you apply two rules that collide to the same elements, browser will choose the last one that was declared. Change order of Your media queries.

Comment: Here based on the screen resolution only one style is going to apply so there is no collide. Re order will not work. Because which style is comes last will get apply, that is my question.

Comment: Where is the 2 colliding media query?